# Page level masking with bootstrap and css style on button

Tags: css, angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am not good at css, but here is what I want and what i have tried.

```
<div>
    <div id="propertiesTable" style="padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;" ng-cloak >
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
            <tbody>

                <tr data-ng-repeat="(k,v) in properties">
                    <td>{{ k }}</td>
                    <td>{{ v }}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div style="padding-left: 20px;">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"
            title="Refresh for updated properties"
            ng-click="onRefreshButtonClick()">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh">Refresh</span>
        </button>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

So, I have this cluttered button `glyphicon glyphicon-refresh` inside a `class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"`

I need some space between these two. When I tried padding style it did not work. padding is getting applied to the entire button obviously!

1. How can I achieve padding between `glyphicon glyphicon-refresh` and `class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"` ?
2. When I click on Refresh, I want the `id:propertiesTable` to be masked(meaning light dimness for this part). Is this achievable?

Sorry about this question. Not good at CSS.

Thank you Stackoverflow!

Comment: Break your question up into 2 entirely different questions. number 1 has nothing to do with number 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add a non-breaking space: http://jsfiddle.net/mm6ck3dc/9/

`<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh">&nbsp;Refresh</span>`

Comment: That was nice Adam. I will post the 2nd half as another question. Thank you !

Comment: here is a dim in javascript, if you wanna use it. http://jsfiddle.net/mm6ck3dc/10/